# how to make events listen to dynamically created html elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

im doing this project where i have to clone a todolist whenever i click a plus sign,it clones the todolist.But the dynamically created todolist doesnt listen for any events eventhough i have used .on instead of .click.Please view the image to understand what i m telling.   [The small plus sign in the left side corner is used to clone the entire todolist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BEEe.png)
and the bigger plus sign inside the todolist is used to toggle the visibility of the input field.
When a new todolist is created by clicking on the small plus sign.Event listeners in the new dynamically created todolist doesnt work.

```
    // Check Off Specific Todos By Clicking
    $("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("completed");
    });

    //Click on X to delete Todo
    $("ul").on("click", "span", function(event){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
        if(event.which === 13){
            //grabbing new todo text from input
            var todoText = $(this).val();
            $(this).val("");
            //create a new li and add to ul
            $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText + "</li>")
        }
    });

    $(".fa-plus").on("click",function(){
        $("input[type='text']").fadeToggle();
    });

    $("#test").on("click",function(){
       $("#container").clone().insertAfter( $("#container") );
    });
```

This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/todos.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <i class="fa fa-plus-square" id="test"></i>
<div id="container">
    <h1>To-Do List <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">

    <ul>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Go To Potions Class</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Buy New Robes</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Visit Hagrid</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/todos.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just FYI: adding html dynamically [$("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText + "</li>")] got me into trouble in two ways: One with needing to use a setTimeout to add listeners to these elements, as the browser needs time to update to the new HTML, and second, Content-Security-Policy was disallowing changes like these. It's more work, but it's much better to just use document.createElement for all your new content

Comment: does it help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple trick here to resolve this issue is to pass `true` to the [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method:

```
$("#test").on("click",function(){
    $("#container").clone(true).insertAfter($("#container"));
});
```

This boolean value indicates whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. The default value is `false`. So, when we were calling the `.clone()` method without passing any boolean value, it was just copying the elements but not the event handlers attached to it. But, when we pass the value `true`, it copies both the elements and any event handler attached to it.

Comment: i was wondering how to add the dynamically created new todolist permanently to the html ?can u help me out with that

Comment: Please create a separate question for that.

Comment: Also, while creating the question please add a small demo and minimise the code to a minimum like here is a button and here is a small list, you create a clone of it now this is the issue.. how to resolve it, as it will be easier for others user to understand and help you faster.